# Bash Script - Solo obtener los últimos 3 directorios

Tags: linux, bash, servidor, script, consola

tengo instalado en un servidor linux un script de copias mysql que hace copias rotativas, guardando los últimos 30dias.

Y me gustaria hacer un script que me coja por ejemplo los últimos 3 días y los empaquete en un tar.gz

Tengo el siguiente script

```
DIA=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`

cd /tmp
mkdir copia
cd copia

export GZIP=-9
tar -czvf $DIA-mysql.tar.gz  /root/backups/mysql
```

El directorio tengo un listado como este

Me gustaría poder obtener por ejemplo los  3 últimos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: más que hacerlo a mano, lo mismo te vale la pena utilizar herramientas como logrotate

Answer (score 1):

Basta con obtener los nombres

```
ls
```

ordenarlos

```
sort
```

y quedarnos solo con los 3 últimos:

```
tail -n 3
```

Todo junto, sería

```
ls | sort | tail -n 3
```

<sub>No tengo claro que sea necesario el `sort`, pero como no tengo un directorio con archivos con esos nombres para probar, pues lo he puesto.</sub>

Comment: [parsear `ls` no es recomendable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), pues tiene un formato bastante frágil. Mejor usar herramientas como `find`.

Comment: Quizá `ls -1 | ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Así se podrían encontrar los 3 últimos (orden alfabético ascendente) directorios del directorio actual:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -a ! -name '.' -exec basename {} \; | sort | tail -n 3
```

---

`find -maxdepth 1 -type d -a ! -name '.' -exec basename {} \;` significa buscar solo en el directorio actual todos los directorios que no se llamen `.` (excluir el directorio actual) y para cada resultado ejecutar `basename` para eliminar el `./` del comienzo. Estas son sus partes:

1. `-maxdepth 1` hace que solo se consideren los archivos o directorios del directorio actual y no se continúe buscando dentro de los subdirectorios.
2. `-type d` hace que solo se consideren los directorios y se ignoren otros tipos de archivos (archivos regulares, enlaces simbólicos, etc.).
3. `-a` es una conjunción (and).
4. `!` es una negación (not).
5. `-name '.'` indica buscar el archivo o directorio llamado `.` (previamente se niega).
6. `-exec basename {} \;` indica ejecutar `basename` para cada resultado (`{}` es donde va a reemplazarse por cada resultado). Puede ser opcional si los resultados con un `./` al comienzo no son problemáticos.

`sort` ordena alfabéticamente su entrada de forma ascendente.

`tail -n 3` solo muestra las últimas 3 líneas de la entrada.

Una explicación más detallada de estos comandos se puede ver en: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+-maxdepth+1+-type+d+-a+%21+-name+%27.%27+-exec+basename+%7B%7D+%5C%3B+%7C+sort+%7C+tail+-n+3